# How do I set camera to chase an entity, but only in x direction?

Tags: andengine

So I have a small Sprite, and I want it to be able to jump/fly but I don't want the camera to follow its y movements, just the x movement. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use BoundCamera class or its extensions to be able to access methods responsible for setting camera bounds.

```
Entity e = new Entity();
e.setPosition(pX, pY);

camera.setChaseEntity(e);
camera.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 50);
camera.setBoundsEnabled(true);
```

First two parameter are minimal X and Y bound position (in this case bottom left corner) Two next are maximum bound position. Which means camera`s position will not exceed 800 x and 50 y value.Change as per your requirement.Hoping it may helps you.